# Create filtered index

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to create a filtered index on (Column1 = Column2) condition:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Document_IsBalanced]
ON [ACC].[Document] ([DocumentID] ASC)
WHERE SumCredit = SumDebit
ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Error Message is :

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'

Comment: Please post the statement you're issuing

Comment: Also: you can have a *simple* check in your filtered index expression - like `WHERE Column1 IS NOT NULL` or something like that. You **cannot** however compare two columns values - you will get an error `Msg 10735, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect WHERE clause for filtered index 'ix_test' on table 'dbo.XXXXXXX'.`

Comment: My T-SQL Command is : CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Document_IsBalanced] ON [ACC].[Document] ([DocumentID] ASC)
WHERE SumCredit = SumDebit
ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Comment: Quassnoi's answer is correct but the error message is complaining about syntax near `WITH`. Where is that code? The error I get when trying to create your filtered index is `Incorrect WHERE clause for filtered index 'IX_Document_IsBalanced' on table 'Document'.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The docs are quite confusing on this matter, but you cannot really create an index filtered on this condition (since it cannot be used on filtering statistics).

The docs say:

> The filter predicate uses simple comparison logic

without clearly defining "simple", but in fact "simple" means "usable by the filtered statistics". The two have the same limitations.

The statistics can only use equalities, ranges and in-lists agains constants. This means you can only use the following predicates:

```
column = const
column > const
column < const
column IN (const1, const1)
```

and their variations (`BETWEEN` etc), possibly combined with an `AND` (not even `OR`).

Comment: I have successfully used != on a filtered index as well.

Answer (score -5):

Filtered indexes are SQL Server 2012 feature - here's the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) from MSDN on the syntax

for example:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX FIBillOfMaterialsWithEndDate
    ON Production.BillOfMaterials (ComponentID, StartDate)
    WHERE EndDate IS NOT NULL ;
GO
```

Comment: No no no - filtered indexes were introduced in SQL Server **2008** my friend... - see your own MSDN docs : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372%28v=sql.100%29.aspx